# Getting data between two given dates is returning nothing Eloquent

Tags: mysql, datetime, eloquent

I am trying to fetch data if the current date and time falls between start time and end time. Here's what I have done:

```
$coupon = Coupons::where('start_datetime', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:m:s'))
                        ->where('end_datetime', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:m:s') )
                        ->paginate(6);
```

But this query is not returning anything. I tried to change it see its SQL query but it is all good. My `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` formats are both `dateTime` ('0000-00-00 00:00:00') in my db. I also tried using the `date('Y-m-d h:m:s')` function in PHP but it's also the same result. How can I possibly do it in my query?

Comment: Try using a duration and subtracting the two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing conditions can help you:

```
$coupon = Coupons::where('start_datetime', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:m:s'))
                        ->where('end_datetime', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:m:s') )
                        ->paginate(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys, I have figured it out. My DB column is using 24hr format and my query is using 12hr format only. So I have just changed `Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d h:m:s')` to `Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:m:s')`